# How to sort an array in ascending order from Key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
$arr = array('XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

Now, using a function, I generate the following array based on the previous one. When doing a `print_r($new_arr)` and echoing it in `pre` tags, this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => l
    [3] => m
    [2] => s
    [5] => xl
    [1] => xs
)
```

However, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => xs
    [2] => s
    [3] => m
    [4] => l
    [5] => xl
)
```

Now, I did some searching on S.O and found about the `ksort` function. Further reading in the PHP Docs, shows that this is the one to be used but when I use `ksort` as follows and the echoing the output, I get the value `1` only, instead of an array of values as I expected to get in the previous paragraph above:

```
$sorted_arr = ksort($new_arr);
```

On echoing `$sorted_arr` in `pre` tags, this is the output(it's just the number one):

```
1
```

I'm not really sure what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ksort` doesn't return the sorted array, it works on a reference of the array. You'll find the array you passed in should be sorted.

Comment: ksort sorts the array and returns true/false. You don't have to assign anything. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) returns a boolean value not the sorted array. Output the `$new_arr` variable instead.

Comment: Aha! I see. I should not have assigned the `ksort()`. Thanks

Comment: @nTuply It happens to the rest of us. Just practice reading through the documentation and take note of the returned values and you'll be fine. Good luck and happy developing!

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). You will find out `ksort` returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure. Print the `$new_arr` instead, it was passed as reference to `ksort()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) function.

Note that the function sorts the input array in place, rather than returning a sorted version. The return value is a bool and just indicates success or failure.